# Generate Multiple Table DDL Along With the Data And All Constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

How can I generate MS-SQL Server DDL for multiple tables along the all constraints and data insertion statments for data currently in DataBase.

In addtion to this I want to Know If I run this DDL on any other system will I have to make any corresponding changes apart from changing connection_String in my C# code?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I got a method to generate the DDL to create tables looking for a method to find i can get the data too.